# Load and override current page url and contents with jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a product list on my index.php and on clicking the name of the product, I want to override the index.php contents and url by loading the product_details.php page along with it's contents and url without page reload.

I used the below code to override the url but I don't have a clue on how to load the contents.

```
$(document).on("click", ".view", function(e) { 

  e.preventDefault();

  var url = $(this).attr(href);

  history.pushState('obj', 'Product Details', url); 


 });
```

Here is an example of what I want

[www.flutterwave.com/store/sativamerch](http://www.flutterwave.com/store/sativamerch)

Comment: Research `pushstate`  `history.pushState(null, null, url);`

Comment: Checkout my code.. I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this...

$(document).on("click", ".view", function(e) {

```
       e.preventDefault();
    
       var url = $(this).attr("href");
  

    $('#loader').css("display","inline-block"); // display's a loader while loading 
    
        
     setTimeout(function() {  
    
            $("#products").load(url + " #details", function() {
    
       history.replaceState('obj', 'Product_Details', url);  });
          
        }, 2000);
       
    });
```